# Cohomology of root data

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, root-systems, weyl-group

Let $(X,\Phi,X^\vee,\Phi^\vee)$ be a semisimple root datum (in the sense of SGAIII), and $W_0$ its (finite) Weyl group. What is known about the cohomology groups $H^n(W_0, X^\vee)$ ?

Comment: You should probably elaborate on your definition, since root data means slightly different things to different people.

Comment: What do you mean by a *simple* root datum?

Comment: By that I mean semisimple and indecomposable. Obviously it suffices to consider indecomposable ones, once you restrict to semisimple ones. I reworded it now to make it less confusing.

Comment: I think that for $G={\rm SL}(n)$ we have $H^1(S_n, X^\vee)\cong\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Thanks Mikhail! Am I right to assume that this is due to your own calculations, and that you are not aware of any published results concerning these groups?

Comment: Yes, you are right.